Issue with Google Play System Update on Rooted Samsung Galaxy A15 4G
After initiating the Google Play System update, the phone reboots automatically as part of the process. However, after this first reboot, the phone reboots itself again. Following this second reboot, I find that the update has not been installed. Instead, the system seems to have reverted to its previous, non-updated state.
Also, I have two logs: A14 4G logcat (github.com), which was from my first attempt, and A14 4G logcat (github.com). For the second log, I removed Google Meet and tried again.
The ROM on my device is up-to-date, so I am trying to understand why the Google Play System update isn’t installing properly and how I might fix this issue. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
